# Javaのhttp通信プラグインretrofitのURLの定義が出来ない

Tags: android, java, retrofit

retrofit http://square.github.io/retrofit/ を使って、APIの定義を書こうと思うのですが
http://example.com/hoge?kage20150825
http://example.com/hoge?kage20150826
http://example.com/hoge?kage20150827
のように、?の後の項目を任意に変えるにはどうしたらよいのでしょうか

```
public interface APIInterface {
@GET("/hoge?{date}")
void  getActivityNotificationList(@Path("date") String date, Callback<xxx> xxx);
}
```

と書いたのですが

java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: APIInterface.getActivityNotificationList: URL query string "{date}" must not have replace block.

と出て拒否されてしまいます。

URLの構造を変える事は出来ないです。

Comment: `GET`通信でクエリパラメータを扱う場合には[`Query`](http://square.github.io/retrofit/javadoc/retrofit/http/Query.html)を使うのですが、`key=value`形式でないURLには対応していないのではないでしょうか。

Comment: みたいですね。@QueryMap でどうにか近い所までもっていけましたが、"hoge?date=" とイコールはどうしても消えませんでした。

Answer (score 2, accepted):

今更、かつ正しい使い方とも思えませんが、
以下のようにすると、実現はできる様です。

インターフェースの定義

```
@GET("/hoge")
Call<ResponseBody> getActivityNotificationList( @QueryMap Map<String, Object> map);
```

実行

```
Map<String, Object> map = new HashMap<String, Object>();
map.put("kage20150825", new Object() { public String toString() { return null;}});
service.getActivityNotificationList(map);
```

retrofitのソースを見たところ、パラメータの値をtoStringした結果がnullの場合に、
クエリパラメータに=をつけない様だったので、その動作を利用しました。
実装を見る限り、他の方法では実現できなそうです。